# Version Control for non-programmers

Tags: version-control

Can someone recommend a version control engine + GUI that will be good for non-technical users?  I'm perfectly fine with using Subversion with my team of developers, but I want to find something that will help the rest of our company.
We are a design firm that deal with these type of files: Photoshop, Vectorworks, Microsoft Office, PDFs, etc.
I find GUIs such as SVNx and even Versions(which is pretty nice) too difficult and techy for our designers to use.  It's hard for them to understand the idea of working directories and its relationship to a repository.

We are a small company and don't have a huge budget so we would like to stay opensource if possible.

Comment: I think the question entails a contradiction, as in: is there a book that an illiterate can read?

Comment: And an excellent example of something almost anyone can read would be the in flight safety manual all airplanes carry that directs you what to do in case of an emergency.  This if course assumes you can see, but never assumes you can read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your non-techies are on a Mac, I would recommend SVN with [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/) from Zennaware. It's not open-source, but not expensive either. Our designers love it and it's got a great GUI.

Comment: rich, this looks pretty good.  I especially like the side by side comparison view for image files and PSD's.  One quick question, since it's impossible to merge changes or diff non-text files, how does your designers work with the software?  Do they always checkout files with locks so that no one else can checkout?

Comment: in my experience i haven't run into a situation where the designers need to diff non-text files or perform merges, so they always turn to us to perform some of those more advanced tasks anyway. as far as locks our team is pretty small and we just solve conflicts as they pop up, which has been somewhat rare.

Answer (score 6):

[Drop Box](http://www.getdropbox.com/).

Comment: I like drop box as an app but I don't think that drop box will help out the situation.  It doesn't version files.

Comment: http://www.davidherrold.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/dropbox_versioning.jpg

Comment: This gets +5 by my mediawiki solution gets -1?  :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you use TortiousCVS|SVN, its not too bad. Its a GUI/file based approach so its fairly straight forward. I've had non-technical people use it and like it.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't SharePoint come with Windows Server? It can handle file versions.

Comment: Yeah but sharepoint is also a steaming pile of crap.

Comment: I wish I could upvote that comment several times.

Comment: @Justin - and your alternative is?

Comment: Something less than $1000 to license preferably.

Answer (score 1):

I can say that Subversion and Perforce are both problematic to non-technical users.  We have been using Perforce as a document repository with some success.  Though we have had more mistakes and problems than I care to talk about.  We had slightly more success with Subversion and TortoiseSVN but even it was too difficult to most non-programmers to wrap their heads around.  Though if you are lucky enough to have Mac OSX in the office, I would give [rich's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665214/version-control-for-non-programmers/1665220#1665220) a try.

I would recommend looking for a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) that supports history instead of a source repository.  You should be able to find something out there that will do the job without too much work on your part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Pages/Default.aspx) or [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/). They both have a WebDAV interface which allows you to directly open and close files in the repository from Office and other current applications.  SharePoint works better with Microsoft Office, as there are Microsoft specific WebDAV extensions in Office. Additionally, Confluence only offers WebDAV through a plugin.

Both of them are commercial products, though Confluence does have a [shared source license](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/features/open.jsp), allowing you to make local modifications.

Comment: Is SharePoint or Confluence opensource?

Answer (score 0):

[Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/en/) has a pretty [straightforward interface](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/explorer/en/visual-tour-windows.html) for the basic version-control tasks.

At some level, you're going to have to explain the basic concepts even to non-technical folk for them to make any use of it (there's no real way to "hide" the concept of committing your changes, for instance), but at the very least Bazaar's UI makes it pretty simple to do so, and keeps the option complexity down.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check [NeverOverwrite](http://www.neveroverwrite.com/).

It keeps all versions of your files automatically. Sounds like an an ideal solution for non-developer.

Comment: That's a dead link now.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Wiki with some minimal version control built in ... like [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use source repository control for binary files like Photoshop, Vectorworks, Microsoft Office, PDFs, etc? I think Content Management System works better for you. Try using [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/), it's opensource and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I find [sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) extremely intuitive for git/mercurial (no support for svn). It is for Mac and windows. It makes common operations like switching branches, merging, branching, reverting  - which otherwise would be painful - quite easy. 
But for your case I think VC solutions (that was built for coders) is not optimal as you will not be able to see differences between two versions of files as .psd, .doc, .pdf - these cannot be handled by the internal diff tool - so you are missing a lot of the power of version control